# Unable to perform Cloud Function trigger a HTTP triggered Cloud Function that doesn't allow unauthenticated invocations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a situation where I am trying to create two Cloud Functions namely CF1 & CF2 and I have one Cloud Scheduler. Both cloud functions are having authenticated invocation enabled. My flow is Cloud Scheduler will trigger CF1. On completion of CF1, the CF1 will trigger CF2 as a http call. I have referred [Cannot invoke Google Cloud Function from GCP Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60055422/cannot-invoke-google-cloud-function-from-gcp-scheduler) to access authenticated CF1 from Cloud Scheduler and able to access CF1. But I am getting problem when accessing CF2 from CF1. The CF1 does not trigger CF2 and also not giving any error message. Do we need to follow any other technique when accessing authenticated Cloud Function from another authenticated Cloud Function.

CF1 code:

```
import json
import logging
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession


def main(request):
    # To read parameter values from request (url arguments or Json body).
    raw_request_data = request.data
    string_request_data = raw_request_data.decode("utf-8")
    request_json: dict = json.loads(string_request_data)

    request_args = request.args

    if request_json and 'cf2_endpoint' in request_json:
        cf2_endpoint = request_json['cf2_endpoint']
    elif request_args and 'cf2_endpoint' in request_args:
        cf2_endpoint = request_args['cf2_endpoint']
    else:
        cf2_endpoint = 'Invalid endpoint for CF2'

    logger = logging.getLogger('test')
    try:
        session = FuturesSession()
        session.get("{}".format(cf2_endpoint))
        logger.info("First cloud function executed successfully.")

    except RuntimeError:
        logger.error("Exception occurred {}".format(RuntimeError))
```

CF2 code:

```
import logging

def main(request):
    logger = logging.getLogger('test')
    logger.info("second cloud function executed successfully.")
```

Current output logs:

```
First cloud function executed successfully.
```

Expected output logs:

```
First cloud function executed successfully.
second cloud function executed successfully.
```

Note: Same flow is working if I use unauthenticated access to the both cloud functions.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are happening here:

1. You're not using `request-futures` entirely correctly. Since the request is made asynchronously, you need to block on the result before the function implicitly returns, otherwise it might return before your HTTP request completes (although it probably is in this example):

```py
session = FuturesSession()
future = session.get("{}".format(cf2_endpoint))
resp = future.result()  # Block on the request completing
```

2. The request you're making to the second function is not actually an authenticated request. Outbound requests from a Cloud Function are not authenticated by default. If you looked at what the actual response is above, you would see:

```
>>> resp.status_code
403
>>> resp.content
b'\n<html><head>\n<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">\n<title>403 Forbidden</title>\n</head>\n<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>\n<h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>\n<h2>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/function_two</code> from this server.</h2>\n<h2></h2>\n</body></html>\n'
```

You could jump through a lot of hoops to properly authenticate this request, as detailed in the docs: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function

However, a better alternative would be to make your second function a "background" function and invoke it via a PubSub message published from the first function instead:

```py
from google.cloud import pubsub

publisher = pubsub.PublisherClient()
topic_name = 'projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic}'.format(
    project_id=<your project id>,
    topic='MY_TOPIC_NAME',  # Set this to something appropriate.
)

def function_one(request):
    message = b'My first message!'
    publisher.publish(topic_name, message)

def function_two(event, context):
    message = event['data'].decode('utf-8')
    print(message)
```

As long as your functions have the permissions to publish PubSub messages, this avoids the need to add authorization to the HTTP requests, and also ensures at-least-once delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Function provide [REST API interface](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest) what include *call* method that can be used in another Cloud Function HTTP invokation.
Although the documentation [mention using Google-provided client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained) there is still non one for Cloud Function on Python.

And instead you need to use general Google API Client Libraries. [This is the python one].[3](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/tree/master/docs)

Probably, the main difficulties while using this approach is an understanding of authentification process.
Generally you need provide two things to build a client service:
*credentials* ans *scopes*.

The simpliest way to get credentials is relay on Application Default Credentials (ADC) library. The rigth documentation about that are:

1. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production
2. https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/auth.md

The place where to get *scopes* is the each REST API function documentation page.
Like, [OAuth scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/call#authorization-scopes)

The complete code example of calling 'hello-world' clound fucntion is below.
Before run:

1. Create default Cloud Function on GCP in your project.

- Keep and notice the default service account to use
- Keep the default body.

2. Notice the *project_id*, *function name*, *location* where you deploy function.
3. If you will call function outside Cloud Function environment (locally for instance) setup the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS according the doc mentioned above
4. If you will call actualy from another Cloud Function you don't need to configure credentials at all.

```python
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.discovery_cache.base import Cache
import google.auth

import pprint as pp

def get_cloud_function_api_service():
    class MemoryCache(Cache):
        _CACHE = {}

        def get(self, url):
            return MemoryCache._CACHE.get(url)

        def set(self, url, content):
            MemoryCache._CACHE[url] = content

    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']

    # If the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set,
    # ADC uses the service account file that the variable points to.
    #
    # If the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS isn't set,
    # ADC uses the default service account that Compute Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine, App Engine, Cloud Run,
    # and Cloud Functions provide
    #
    # see more on https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production
    credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes)

    service = build('cloudfunctions', 'v1', credentials=credentials, cache=MemoryCache())
    return service


google_api_service = get_cloud_function_api_service()
name = 'projects/{project_id}/locations/us-central1/functions/function-1'
body = {
    'data': '{ "message": "It is awesome, you are develop on Stack Overflow language!"}' # json passed as a string
}
result_call = google_api_service.projects().locations().functions().call(name=name, body=body).execute()
pp.pprint(result_call)
# expected out out is:
# {'executionId': '3h4c8cb1kwe2', 'result': 'It is awesome, you are develop on Stack Overflow language!'}
```