# Limit Cloud Function Authentication for topic-triggered function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that is Triggered by a topic: `processLL`
The default authentication for this Cloud Function is `Allow unauthenticated` by default. I don't want unauthenticated access to this function, but how do I limit unauthenticated access to this function but still allow it to (only) be triggered by subscribing to its topic trigger?

Comment: Update: the answer by nebulastic to this similar question works:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235853/how-to-invoke-cloud-function-from-cloud-scheduler-with-authentication

...along with removing allUsers from the subscribing Cloud Function. Basically set

member=${PROJECT_ID}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
role="roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"

Comment: Do you have your answer? If not, did you create a PubSub triggered Cloud Function? or a HTTP triggered Cloud Function with a PubSub Http Push subscription that call the function http endpoint?

Comment: Yes - it's a pub/sub (topic=processLL) function, and setting the service account as the member and role=roles/cloudfunctions.invoker was successful

Comment: Great!! Have fun now!